# Finding the volume of surface bounded by planes and $x=y^2$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Find the volume of the surface that's bounded by $x=y^2$ and $x=z, z=0, x=1.$

Looking at the $yz-$plane this seems to form a triangle that's bounded by $y=z$ and $y=1$. I'm not entirely sure if I should form an integral of the form $$\int\int f(y,z) \ dz \ dy$$
or some other way around. From $x=z$ I would have that $z=y^2$ so $f(y,z) = y^2-z$? Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want the volume you can integrade $\int\int\int_V dxdydz$ where V is the volume enclosed by the surface. This means that $f(x,y,z) = 1$. From this and the surfaces you have mentioned, you have to slice that volume in order to get an easy identification of the boundaries on each axis.

Comment: I managed to get something of the form $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{-\sqrt{x}}^{\sqrt{x}} \int_{0}^{x} 1 \ dz \ dy \ dx$, but this equals $2x\sqrt{x}$, which doesn't seem to be right.

Comment: The result of the first two integrals is $2x\sqrt{x}= 2x^{3/2}$ but then $\int_0^1 2x^{3/2} dx= \left[\frac{4}{5} x^{5/2}\right]_0^1= \frac{4}{5}$.  Do you have a problem with that?

Comment: Ah, I forgot to integrate the last bit. However, I'm not entirely sure I got the bounds right.

Answer (score 1):

I had to draw in order to get a better view of the volume. First I handled the parabola given by $x=y^2, \forall z\in \mathbb{R}$ which is cut by the planes $x=z, \forall y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $z=0, \forall (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$. It gave something like this:

[image]

In order to get rid of the $z$ variable I did

$$\int_0^x dz = x$$

Next all I have to take care of is in the $xy$ plane where I also used the parabola $x=y^2$ but added $x=1$. This gives this picture:

[image]

Now I choose to integrate

$$\int_{y^2}^1 x dx = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{y^4}{2}$$

Finally $y\in [-1,1]$ which gives

$$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{2} - \frac{y^4}{2} dy = \frac{4}{5}$$

Unless I messed up the reasoning, this is the approach I went with.